# Understanding how to populate Google Analytics event tracking values

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to track certain values in my web-app. For example I want to know how many lines are in a certain text-area...

I am trying to use `_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)`
(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

But I am kind of confused as how to fittingly populate the values.
Would category be something like "user data"? Is the action or the label "number of lines"?
How can I populate the values so that I can then later "work" with the data best in Google Analytics?

Thanks

Comment: By "how many lines are in a certain text-area" do you mean that you're trying to track how many lines a user has entered into a text area upon submission? Just trying to clear up the objective here.

Comment: @Greg, yes that is what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

#### Category

Category is just the top level grouping. In this case, it might be something like `"Textarea"`.

#### Action

"Action" is the second level data-point; it need not actually be an action. If all you want to do is track the number of rows, you could just call this `"Row Count"` (which could allow for grouping other textarea related metrics in the same category).

#### Label (opt.)

Let's say you want to track it both as its own unit, as well as a numeric value.

So, you could set the label to be a string, like `"12 rows"`.

#### Value (opt.)

And you could set the value to just the numeric value, like `12` -- this will give you total and average value.

#### Non-Interaction? (opt.)

Finally, since this isn't tracking an interaction, you wouldn't want it to affect bounce rate, so you set the `opt_noninteraction` flag to `true`.

### Result

All of that together ends up looking like:

```
var row_count = jQuery('textarea').html().split("\n").length; //or something like this
_gaq.push(["_trackEvent", "Textarea", "Row Count", row_count + " rows", row_count, true ]);
```